# Counting such functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

How many total functions are there from a set with $3$ elements to a set with $4$ elements?

Just as a reminder, "total" functions are simply functions defined on all the elements of given domain. I calculated it as $4^3$ from multiplication principle, but unsure on that solution. Moreover, I am also curious on if we replaced "total" function with "one-to-one" and "onto", would the same answer be correct in both cases?

Would be welcomed to know your thoughts on this! Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone, please, check my answer and whether it is true for other functions, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, by the definition of a function you must use all $3$ elements and there are four choices for each resulting in $4^{3}$ distinct possibilities. For one-to-one we must use all $3$ elements in the domain but the number of possibilities decreases for each element used (since one-to-one means that $ x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$ so that for the first element there are $4$ possibilities, for the second, $3$ possibilities, and for the third, $2$ possibilities giving us $4 \cdot 3\cdot 2 = 24 
$ possibilities. There are no surjective functions since if we map each element to a single element of the codomain (as is required by a function), there is always some element that is left over in the codomain since $4>3$.